# Programmatically get a list of all included Perl packages

Tags: perl, perl-module

Does anyone know of a way to iterate, at Perl run time, through all packages that have actually been included (i.e. `use`'d or `require`'d) in a Perl program? I have found lots of answers regarding how to find all **installed** packages, but that's not what I'm interested in. I specifically want to get a list of only those packages that the program has actually included. Is this possible at all?

I'm using Perl 5.26.0, by the way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The hash `%INC` contains all the loaded packages, see [perlvar](http://p3rl.org/perlvar).

```
print "$_\n" for keys %INC;
```